how do I fix tough go with teeth bone?
I use metarig by the way. so after I parenting automatic weight tough and rig. seem like the top teeth bone control tough. but not the tough bone. so how should I fix this? thanks for answer much.


What do you mean by "tough"? - Maybe you mean "tongue"?

Yeah. I mean Tongue. Sorry. I kinda bad at spelling sometimes.
